# WiFi Direct Not working on Samsung Devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wifi, sharing

I am working on a project based on File sharing via WiFi. This project works properly on every device except Samsung Devices. Here is my Code.

```
public class MainReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = MainReceiver.class.getName();
    public static final String ACTION_TRANSFER_DONE = "action_transfer_done";
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    public MainReceiver(){
        super();
    }

    public MainReceiver(MainActivity activity){
        super();
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("action_transfer_done"))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "transfer done");
            List<String> mFileNames = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(ServerService.FILES_NAME);
            mActivity.transferDone(mFileNames);
        }
    }
}
```